# Can't set a variable in javascript while using autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

This is my current code:

```
var areaid;

$( "#FindCentre" ).autocomplete({
    //Doesn't give the right value here.
    source: "databasescripts/findcentre.php?AreaID=" + areaid,
    minLength: 2,
    select: function( event, ui ) {
  },
 html: true,
});

$( "#FindArea" ).autocomplete({
    source: "databasescripts/findarea.php",
    minLength: 2,
    select: function( event, ui ) {
    areaid = ui.item.id;
    alert(areaid);
    //Alerts the correct value here.
  },
 html: true,
});
```

When users type into FindArea it alerts the correct value, however when they then type into FindCentre it will always come back as being undefined. I've tried reading the ID from FindArea in FindCentre but I can't seem to do that either.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Have you try getting the value directly from the control ? $("#FindArea").val().

Comment: @artm is correct... I got involved in the fiddle and I landed up 5 minutes late. :) [Fiddle may help](http://jsfiddle.net/shubh0602/4h60q16z/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you make the first autocomplete call, it sets up the autocomplete with the static value, i.e. areaid = undefined. If you want to use autocomplete with dynamic value you need to do something like this:

```
source: function(request, response) {
    $.ajax({
       url: "databasescripts/findcentre.php?AreaID=" + areaid //or + $("#FindArea").val()
    });
}
```

Comment: It now gives the correct URL, however the second autocomplete doesn't want to show any search suggestions. Any ideas?

Comment: @pyy I think that's a separate issue but if you still have them remove all the unnecessary code from 2nd autocomplete, i.e. `select: function`

Comment: Thanks, I have removed that. It still doesn't want to search, but I'll have a fiddle around with it and see if I can fix it :)